# C++ Initialize Vector each element with parameters of another vector

Tags: c++, vector

I want to create a std::vector in which each elements constructor is called with the correct upper and lower node. Is there a way to do it within the : -space. Using a loop seems utterly inelegant and wrong at this place.

```
Node::Node(std::vector<Node> LowerNodes) : LowerLinks{ LowerNodes.size(), std::vector<Node>(LowerNodes.size(), *this), LowerNodes }
{
}
```

where

```
class Link {
public:
    explicit Link();
    Link(Node &Upper, Node &Lower);
    Node *UpperNode;
    Node *LowerNode;
};

Link::Link() : UpperNode(nullptr), LowerNode(nullptr)
{
}

Link::Link(Node &Upper, Node &Lower) : UpperNode(&Upper), LowerNode(&Lower)
{
}
```

Comment: Your question is missing some crucial information. Whats `LowerLink`? What does `Node` look like? From what you provided, my best guess would be that the problem is due to not respecting [the rule of 3/5/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: The ": - space" is the constructor initialization list (or just init list). Look on cppreference.com for possible std::vector constructors

Comment: If the initialization is supposed to copy the Nodes then why do you use Node* in the Link class? Drop the * and define the right copy/move constructors for Node and you simply have `: UpperNode(Upper), LowerNode(Lower) { }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are referring to [MIL (Member Initialization List)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) by ": -space"